# Null FK References caused a FK Constraint Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a deployment, I had to rollback because the SQL caused a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT error.  The table has millions of rows.  Can anyone see anything in this SQL that would cause that?

I no longer have the original message handy like this:

> FOREIGN KEY constraint "FSomeTable1"

...it was literally VERY vanilla

**OTHER INFORMATION:**

- This was a NEW COLUMN
- The SEED DATA was to be executed in another script, so no data was in `tResult_Status` yet

**TABLE DEFINITIONS:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable](
    [Claim_ID] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    ...other columns do exist...
    [Result_Status_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Claim_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [stp].[tResult_Status](
    [Result_Status_Id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DResult_Status]  DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()),
    [Result_Status_Name] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [System_Value_Indicator] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [Executed_By_Name] [NVARCHAR](400) NOT NULL,
    [Executed_Datetime] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PResult_Status] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Result_Status_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**DEPLOYMENT SCRIPT STATEMENTS:**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FSomeTable1] FOREIGN KEY([Result_Status_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tResult_Status] ([Result_Status_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FSomeTable1]
GO
```

Comment: Can you state to total error message

Comment: What are the data types of the two columns? Can you post (a partial) create table script for the two tables used in the FK?

Comment: Select * from SomeTable WHERE Result_Status_Id NOT IN (SELECT result_Status_id FROM tResult_Status) should show the offending rows?

Is the field NULLABLE in SomaTable?

Comment: Thanks, so it is not a type mismatch, please follow Igor's solution to find out if you have orphan records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you have a value in SomeTable that has no corresponding value in tResult_Status no the FK constraint cannot be created. You can find which records do not have valid values with a query like this (based on your table names).

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tResult_Status r WHERE r.Result_Status_Id = s.Result_Status_Id)
```

Comment: It was a NEW COLUMN

Comment: Are you sure, that there are no processes/code which writes anything into the new column?

Comment: Yes, this is why I am preplexed & none of teh DBA's have answers - which is why I am writiing

Comment: Anyways, it is worth a quick check.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO - then you need to capture the original and complete error message and share that because the only way you can get the error message you described above is orphaned values in the `sometable` table.